# Why do the Autofac has such a name?

Tags: autofac, semantics, abbreviation

Why do the Autofac has such a name?

I mean does it mean something like `auto facility` or something else? I know well what is Autofac, how and for what it is used. Here I am interested in solely the framework`s name.

Comment: Auto(matic) Fac(tory)

Comment: @GerardoGrignoli, thank you. I am just curious where did you get it from? Is it documented somewhere or should one just guess it?